# colon and quotes show up as diamonds in ubuntu 12.10 server edition via virtualbox 4.2

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, ubuntu-12.10

i typed out the following

```
bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/gist/4372049)"
```

I get this in my ubuntu vm

[image: what i see in my ubuntu vm]

Inside the vm i also cannot scroll up and down like the way I can do so using SSH into a a Rackspace ubuntu server for e.g.

Is there a way to do all this? Or I am better off finding a way to SSH into the ubuntu guest OS?

Answer (score 1):

I am using mac os x as host so I have decided to choose the option of using my terminal to ssh into my virtual box ubuntu.

first select the vm inside virtual box and go to settings > network > portforwarding

[image]

then add in the rule with host port as 3022 and guest port as 22 and the name as ssh. Leave everything else as blank.

[image]

install ssh server packages in the guest ubuntu os

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

finally open up your terminal and then type the following if you want to login as root

```
ssh -p 3022 root@127.0.0.1
```

acknowledgements to comments and answers from:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10532299/80353

and

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906441/how-to-ssh-to-a-virtualbox-ubuntu-guest-externally-through-a-windows-host#comment19298721_10532299